# Unable to access values from Json Rest api result in SharePoint Workflow 2013

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, json, workflow-variable

I'm calling rest API in SharePoint workflow in SharePoint designer. I'm looping through the results and  trying to access the values using key and trying to put them in email body . I'm using

```
"Get d/results([%Variable: index%])/X_start_00 from Variable:Jsonresponse (Output to Variable: startdate)"
```

I'm trying to include this start date in email body . Here `variable:index` is for looping to fetch the corresponding start date for each record.

But when i get the email the start date is being displayed as `'1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`' and when i included the `Variable:Jsonresponse` in the email body then i see a date for start date in the Json response. I tried so many different things but couldn't figure this out.